# Why do RelativeLayout buttons override each other?

Tags: android, android-layout, overriding, android-button, android-relativelayout

I seem to be having trouble using relative links to display buttons. They stick together, like buttons overriding each other, and I've tried to get them to not stick, but to no avail.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/formation"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Laws" />
<Button 
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Qualifications of a naval officer" />
<Button
    android:layout_weight="1.0" 
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Code of Conduct" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while creating any xml file, keep in mind that every widget is unique by its id, so first of all you have to assign id to each widget.

Now, here you are using Relative Layout. so every widget you added here will relate to each other.

Now see this code, i did change in your code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/formation"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn1"
android:layout_weight="1.0"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Laws" />
<Button 
android:id="@+id/btn2"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:layout_below="@+id/btn1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Qualifications of a naval officer" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn3"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:layout_below="@+id/btn2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Code of Conduct" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So all button will display one by one.

Answer (score 0):

This will put things one next to other side ways.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/formation"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Laws" />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Qualifications of a naval officer" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button2"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" 
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Code of Conduct" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/formation" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:text="@string/Laws"  />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
                android:text="Code of Conduct" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
                android:text="Qualifications of a naval officer" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Laws" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn1"
    android:text="Code of Conduct" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn2"
    android:text="Qualifications of a naval officer" />
</RelativeLayout>
```